# Mule 4 set HTTP status in Dataweave

Tags: http, mule, status, dataweave

Hi i've reading a mule 4 documentation a lot but did not find answer for this. How can i set the HTTP status in the dataweave transformer? In mule 3 it was set within the set property component. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `statusCode` attribute in the http:response of the listener to tell it where to pickup the status from. The following example will pick it up from a var called `httpStatus` or default to 200 if the var is not available after flow execution:

```
<http:listener config-ref="api-httpListenerConfig" path="/api/v1/*">
            <http:response statusCode="#[vars.httpStatus default 200]">
                <http:headers>#[vars.outboundHeaders default {}]</http:headers>
            </http:response>
            <http:error-response statusCode="#[vars.httpStatus default 500]">
                <http:body>#[payload]</http:body>
                <http:headers>#[vars.outboundHeaders default {}]</http:headers>
            </http:error-response>
        </http:listener>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response but i need to have this in dataweave transformer as i can have plenty of http.statuses . It should be done by using an expression in transformer but that is all i know

Comment: Yes so set that in your listener and then in your dataweave transformers just set the value of the httpStatus var

Answer (score 1):

Define a variable like below and it should work.

```
<set-variable value="404" doc:name="httpStatus" variableName="httpStatus" />
```